# Counting in lists

Tags: python

I need to write a function, `tag_count`, that takes as its argument a list of strings. It should return a count of how many of those strings are XML tags. You can tell if a string is an XML tag if it begins with a left angle bracket "<" and end with a right angle bracket ">".

```
def tag_count(input_list):
    found = 0
    counts = input_list.count('<')
    for key in input_list:
        if key == counts:
            found += 1
    return found
```

Test for the tag_count function:

```
list1 = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']
count = tag_count(list1)
print("Expected result: 2, Actual result: {}".format(count))
```

Can someone tell me why this does not work - and come up with
something that does using a def function.

At the moment, it is returning: Expected result: 2, Actual result: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def tag_count(input_list):
    found = 0
    for key in input_list:
        if (len(key) > 1) and (key[0] == '<') and (key[-1] == '>'):
            found += 1
    return found
```

You need to check whether the characters in your key correspond to '>' or '<'.
Also, `len(key) > 1` checks whether the string has atleast 2 characters.

Comment: Can you elaborate? If key = '<', then the check fails since `len(key)` is not `> 1`, right?

Comment: Yep, your right. sorry about that. Somehow I mistook `>` for `==`.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your trying to count the number of strings in your list that are a single `'<'`. You need to iterate over your list and count the strings that begin and end with angle brackets:

```
>>> def tag_count(lst):
    return sum(s[0] == '<' and s[-1] == '>' for s in lst)

>>> 
>>> list1 = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>']
>>> count = tag_count(list1)
>>> count
2
>>>
```

If there may be cases where there are empty strings in your data, use `str.starstwith` and `str.endswith` rather than indexing to avoid an `IndexError`:

```
return sum(s.startswith('<') and s.endswith('>') for s in lst)
```

Comment: This would fail if a string s is empty.

Comment: @Cuber True, it would. But the OP never said there would be a case where he had an empty string. I'm writing my answer based only off of the sample data the OP gave. Nevertheless, I'll edit.

Comment: startswith & endswith allow to handle the "string is empty" case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh, sorry. I didn't know you were addressing someone else :) (?)

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you - i am new in the programming languag, so i appreciate your help

Comment: @JakobOlsen Glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Taking [Cuber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8412643/cuber)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772933/counting-in-lists/45773011#45773011) into account, a safe and readable way to count XML tags could be:

```
def is_key_XML(key):
    try :
        return (key[0] == '<') and (key[-1] == '>')
    except IndexError:
        return False

def tag_count(input_list):
    return sum(is_key_XML(k) for k in input_list)
```

And the test could be:

```
list1 = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>', '< Graou', 'L', '<>', '']
count = tag_count(list1)
print("Expected result: 3, Actual result: {}".format(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in a list comprehension notation:

```
requested_strs = len([s for s in input_list if s and s.startswith('<') and s.endswith('>')])
```

Even though it is a simple solution, I don't recommend using regexes in case. Compiling regex to match the strings and matching them will take to much time to perform a simple check as this one..

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['<greeting>', 'Hello World!', '</greeting>', '']
import re
len( [ s for s in list1 if re.match(r'<.*>', s) ] )
```

Output:
2

Comment: @ Jean-François Fabre, yes, thanks, updated.. earlier i also wanted to consider a case when there is string before '<' and after '>'